# How can I test if elements of a string column are contained in a given string?

Tags: pandas

If x is a string column I can use

```
x.str.contains("bla")
```

to get a boolean indicating which elements of x contain the string "bla".

I want to do something very simple: I need the reverse function which is True if the element of x contains the string. Is there a simple way to achieve this without using a regular expression? (i.e. x.str.match(...))

Comment: `~x.str.contains("bla")` ?

Comment: This will give me all elements of x not containing "bla" - I want all elements of x which are contained in the string "bla", i.e. if x[0] = "bl" the element should be selected, whereas if x[0]="asdf" the element should not be selected.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want this :

```
x = pd.Series(["bla", "asdf", "bl"])

#does "bla" contain the string/row ?
m = [s in "bla" for s in x]

out = x.loc[m]
```

Output :

```
print(out)

0    bla
2     bl
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

To conserve a `bool` series, I would use the `apply` method of pandas series. Using the same example of @Timeless, it would be :

```
x = pd.Series(["bla", "asdf", "bl"])

x.apply(lambda r: "bla" in r)
```

Output :

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
```